# SQL Server Where clause with or statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @DepotID INT = 0
DECLARE @UserID INT = 72

    SELECT        EM.EmployeeSurname + ', ' + EM.EmployeeForename + ' ' + UPPER(LEFT(EM.EmployeeForename2,1)) EmployeeName
                , EM.EmployeeMasterPayrollNumber
                , PF.FrequencyDesc
                , EM.EmpCode
                , DPT.DepartmentName
                , D.DepotDepotDescription
                , CAST(EHE.EmployeeHolidayEntitlementRemainingEntitlementDays AS INT) EmployeeHolidayEntitlementRemainingEntitlementDays
                , CAST(EHE.EmployeeHolidayEntitlementDaysAdjustment AS INT) EmployeeHolidayEntitlementDaysAdjustment
                , CAST(EHE.EmployeeHolidayEntitlementHolidayTakenDays AS INT) EmployeeHolidayEntitlementHolidayTakenDays
                , CAST(EHE.EmployeeHolidayEntitlementHolidayBuyBack AS INT) EmployeeHolidayEntitlementHolidayBuyBack
                , EHE.EmployeeHolidayEntitlementComments
                , CAST(EHE.EmployeeHolidayEntitlementCarriedForwardHolidayDays AS INT) EmployeeHolidayEntitlementCarriedForwardHolidayDays
                , CAST(EHE.EmployeeHolidayEntitlementBankHoliday AS INT) EmployeeHolidayEntitlementBankHoliday
                , CAST(EHE.EmployeeHolidayEntitlementBaseEntitlementDays AS INT) EmployeeHolidayEntitlementBaseEntitlementDays

FROM                (((ttimport.EmployeeMaster EM 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.PayrollFrequency PF ON EM.FrequencyDesc = PF.DescCode) 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.Departments DPT ON EM.DepartmentName = DPT.DescCode) 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.EmployeeHolidayEntitlement EHE ON EM.EmpCode = EHE.EmpCode) 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.Depot D ON EM.DepotDepotDescription = D.DescCode

                WHERE   D.DescCode IN (SELECT DepotID FROM maintenance.UserDepot WHERE UserID = @UserID)
                OR      (D.DescCode = @DepotID)


                AND EM.EmployeeMasterLeavingDate IS NULL
```

When it is first called the @DepotID is set to 0. But it can be called again where the @DepotID  can be set to an Int value.

When the procedure is run with @DepotID set to 0 and a value in @UserID it works fine, but when I add a value to the @DepotID it produces a lot more records than it should.

I know there is an issue with the WHERE clause, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly no matter what I try.

I have also tried the following in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE   D.DescCode = @DepotID 
        OR D.DescCode IN (SELECT DepotID FROM maintenance.UserDepot WHERE UserID = @UserID)
```

Comment: Are you missing a parentheses? `where (a or b) and c`

Comment: I'm not sure I have tried a few different combos with parentheses but without any success

Comment: Instead of guessing, comment out parts of the query and add them little by little until you find out what's wrong. It's impossible to even test this query without the table schemas. Even if the schema was available though, commenting out would *still* be the fastest way to fix this. BTW `FROM (((ttimport.` Why? You don't need *any* parentheses in the FROM clause

Comment: Hitting Ctrl+] will move between opening and closing parentheses and brackets. It's also a great way to finding missing parentheses

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have spent the last hour doing what you have suggested

Comment: Keep trying. You don't need those parenthesis around your joins or from clause at all. That's your issue. Remove them all and your query should run.